# JavaScript POP UP Auth Help for FB APP Search

Tags: javascript, facebook

FB APP dint generate pop up AUTH..Kindly help me. I need pop up message like the image : http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1XZrbw0p1ZDhRlCx5atMuBrtzZ9DC0 . kindly help me. here the some codes for my app

```
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "redirect path";
</script>

<body >
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true,
xfbml: true, frictionlessRequests : true, oauth  : true
});
console.log("1");
FB.api('/me', function(response){
if(typeof response.name != 'undefined'){
//accept values
document.forms["Namespace"].submit();
}
if(response.email!=undefined){  
}
},{scope: 'email,publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access'});
};
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  });
</script>   
<script>    
function isRegisteredUser(email,appId){
var urlEmail="url path";
req=GetXmlHttpObject(); 
req.open("GET", urlEmail, true);
req.onreadystatechange = callbackEmailAppIDRegistered;
req.send(null);
}
function postToFeed() {
var b = '';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { 
message: b,
link : 'https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/Namespace/',
name: 'app_name',
caption: '',
picture : 'Pic location',
description: 'cc'
}, function(response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(response));
} else {
alert('Post ID' + response.id);
}
});
}
function callbackEmailAppIDRegistered(){
//some action neeed to perform
}
</script> 
</script>
<div class="main" style="height: auto">
<div id="mfs"></div>
<%
String name="";
String source="";
String width="800";
String height="550";
if(request.getParameter("name")!=null)
{   
name=request.getParameter("name");
}
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("app_name"))
{   source="";
//width="550";
//height="375";
}
%>
</body>
```